# Kohana ORM insert NULL and not empty string

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

In Kohana 3.2, when you overwrite the function 'values' of the ORM, and then do something like:

```
public function values(array $values, array $expected = NULL) {           

  if($values['a_column'] == "") $values['a_column'] = NULL;

  return parent::values($values);
}
```

the NULL value will be transformed into an empty string anyway, which is not the behaviour I want.
Anyone knows a workaround? I couldn't find anything in the documentation or on the web...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this. Just use a filter in your model, like so:-

```
public function filters()
{
  return array(
    'initial_assessment_date' => array(
      array(function($value) {
        return (!$value) ? NULL : $value;
      })
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Great! I worked it around in my case, but this is good to know for later! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because later ORM::values use array_key_exists. You need to use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the value.

Comment: I had thought about that and it works on a create, but not on an update, since unsetting will leave the db value unchanged...

Comment: The lack of this functionality is , quite frankly, astonishing for me.